# jsf primefaces filtering pagination scope

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i am filtering my columns and have used pagination so i have made my backing bean session scoped, i have also made it session scoped because i am loading data from db n dont want it to reload. i am using a view button to select a column and forwarding to a new page to display further information and am using a back button there to return back to the main page.

now my problem is that when i filter my data and hit the view button it shows me the data but when i hit the back button n it goes back to the main page the data is still filtered, i know this is happening cauz i have used session scope n the filtering is persisting. The problem with this is that even thought the data is filtered it doesnt show the value in the filtering cell by which it is filtering. to remove the filtering i have to enter a value into the filtering cell and remove it to get all the data back. i feel like maybe i have a design flaw but cant figure out how to solve it.

code snippet

main page

```
 <p:dataTable var="curridea" value="#{userIdea.ideas}"   filteredValue="#{userIdea.filteredideas}"

    paginator="true" rows="10"  
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">


        <p:column headerText="Employee Name"  filterBy="empname"   

                filterMatchMode="contains">  
            <h:outputText value="#{curridea.empname}" />  
        </p:column> 
 <p:column headerText="View">  
            <h:commandButton value="view" action="#{userIdea.actionController}"  >
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{curridea}" target="#{userIdea.selectedidea}" />  

            </h:commandButton> 
        </p:column>
```

view page

```
<h1 class="title">Your idea Here</h1>
<h:form>
<h:outputText value="#{userIdea.selectedidea.idea}" escape="false" />

<h:commandButton value="back" action="#{userIdea.returnController}"  >


            </h:commandButton>
```

useridea

```
private ArrayList<Idea> filteredideas;

    public ArrayList<Idea> getFilteredideas() {
        return filteredideas;
    }

    public void setFilteredideas(ArrayList<Idea> filteredideas) {
        this.filteredideas = filteredideas;
    }
```

**UPDATE:
i solved it by setting the filtered idea in the view page back button to empty but pllease let me know if there is a better solution i am not seeing**

```
<h:commandButton value="back" action="#{userIdea.returnController}"  >

             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="" target="#{userIdea.filteredideas}" />   
            </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, do not update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by setting the filtered idea in the view page back button to empty but pllease let me know if there is a better solution i am not seeing

```
<h:commandButton value="back" action="#{userIdea.returnController}"  >

             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="" target="#{userIdea.filteredideas}" />   
            </h:commandButton>
```